# LinkButton Click Event Doesn't Fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have created link button from code behind and binded with action like this
but this method Render is never invoked on click event. What I missed here ?

```
            Panel pnlMain = new Panel();
            Panel pnlContent = new Panel();
            LinkButton lbContent = new LinkButton();

            lbContent.Click += new EventHandler(Redirect);

            pnlContent.Controls.Add(lbContent);
            pnlMain.Controls.Add(pnlContent);



          private void Redirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

          }
```

Comment: What method Render?  Do you mean Redirect?  How do you know it's not being invoked?  Maybe you should put some code in the body of the method.

Comment: I am sure that Redirect was never invoked in this sutuation.

Comment: Did anyone click the button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    Panel pnlMain = new Panel();
    Panel pnlContent = new Panel();
    LinkButton lbContent = new LinkButton();
    lbContent.Click += new EventHandler(Redirect);
    Redirect(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    private void Redirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing runat="server" tag? however the compilator should complain about that.

Try this it will work.

In your aspx page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
```

And the codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel pnlMain = new Panel();
            Panel pnlContent = new Panel();
            LinkButton lbContent = new LinkButton();
            lbContent.Text = "click";
            lbContent.Click += new EventHandler(Redirect);

            pnlContent.Controls.Add(lbContent);
            pnlMain.Controls.Add(pnlContent);

            this.form1.Controls.Add(pnlMain);

        }
        private void Redirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```